# java code to read the xml content in mail content

Tags: java, email

Here is the code to get the content if its plain or html.
I want to know how to process the contents if the body of the mail is in xml?

```
MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart)part;    
if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
    body += mbp.getContent().toString();
}
else if (mbp.isMimeType("TEXT/HTML")) {
    body += mbp.getContent().toString(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
MimeBodyPart mbp = (MimeBodyPart)part;
if (mbp.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
    body += mbp.getContent().toString();
} else if (mbp.isMimeType("TEXT/HTML")) {
    body += mbp.getContent().toString(); 
}else if(mbp.isMimeType("text/xml")) {
    body += mbp.getContent().toString(); 
}
```

Is this what you want? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: i want to read a particular email in the inbox which has xml in the content, i have to parse it and send to another email.